# How to change content-type in http-interceptor

Tags: angularjs

I would change the content-type in http- interceptor for the method ' request' ?

I tried the following method without success :

```
 config.headers[Content-Type] = 'application/json, text/plain';
```

Is there a solution ?

code :

```
'request': function(config) {
            config.headers[Content-Type] = 'application/json, text/plain';
            return config || $q.when(config);
        },
```

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the array reference key with quotes like

```
config.headers['Content-Type']
```

for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to register your interceptor with $httpProvider?

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
 });
```